# Trying to get Cryptocurrencies Price Data in Google Sheets with no common coins such us SNX

Tags: web-scraping, google-sheets, xpath, import, google-finance

I have a **google sheet** in which I am some **Cryptocurrencies** Price Data that I get using **googleFinance** or **yahoo**. However, I found it difficult to do this with some coins such as **Synthetix Network Token**.

I have been reading other questions in **Stackoverflow** and applying the suggestions but none seem to work with this particular **cryptocurrency**.

If there is someone who has done this before, could you tell me what approach are you using?

Update:

I have tried this:

```
=GOOGLEFINANCE("SNXGBP")
```

And also this

```
=INDEX(IMPORTXML("https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/SNX-GBP/","//div[@data-reactid='32']"), 2, 1)
```

Both work with the majority of cryptocurrencies.

Comment: Yes, I am going to show what you ask, editing my question.

Comment: is this currency on yahoo finance?

Comment: no, I dont think so. I am asking here for alternatives and how to get the data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try:

```
=IMPORTXML("https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/synthetix-network-token/", 
 "//div[@class='priceValue___11gHJ']")
```

[image]

---

or:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(IMPORTXML("https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/synthetix-network-token/", 
 "//div[@class='priceValue___11gHJ']"), "$", )*GOOGLEFINANCE("CURRENCY:USDGBP")
```

[image]

Comment: Both worked!! Many thanks. And also with other coins. Thnaks

Comment: Hi player0, Your code worked but most of the time for a reason I cant underdtand google sheet report this Could not fetch URL: https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/synthetix-network-token/. So most of the time is not working. I am living in UK and I have notice that, same url is different depending on the country you are.

Comment: you can try to add switch(es) so if import fails it tries again: `=IFERROR(IMPORTXML("https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/synthetix-network-token/", 
 "//div[@class='priceValue___11gHJ']"), IMPORTXML("https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/synthetix-network-token/", 
 "//div[@class='priceValue___11gHJ']"))`

Comment: Both are working now. I will inform you about the results. Many thanks anyway.

Comment: I'm getting the error: "Imported content is empty"
from: "=IMPORTXML("https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/ethereum/","//div[@class='priceValue___11gHJ']")"

Comment: I noted you can get it also from class - 'priceValue smaller price' seems like priceValue with static div is updated. and not yet works.

`=IMPORTXML("https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/saitama-inu/","//div[@class='priceValue smallerPrice']")`

Answer (score 6):

I would suggest using a proper service instead of scraping web pages.

The parsing is just gonna fail eventually and force you to rewrite

`=IMPORTDATA("https://cryptoprices.cc/SNX/")*GOOGLEFINANCE("CURRENCY:USDGBP")`

This request will give you all the price of SNX coin in GBP (using Google Sheets native function to convert USD to GBP)

Comment: This doesn't work for numbers with leading zero's such as "0.354". It's turned into "354". I've tried by importing with importXML with tag "//body" but it's stuck on loading ...

I've currently solved it like this:
****=value(text(ImportXML("cryptoprices-link";".";"en_US");"000000.000000"))****

And it works quite well, though there might be better solutions?